# babel clashing with booktabs and tabularx in custom environment

Tags: tabularx, babel, booktabs

I have a document like this, that is compiled normally:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{myenv}
               {\tabularx{\columnwidth}{X}\toprule}
               {\bottomrule\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
    Foo\\
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I also need to `\usepackage[italian]{babel}`, but if I do so and then compile I get the following error:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\bottomrule ->\noalign 
                       {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
l.16 \end{myenv}
```

and in the PDF output the table has two `\bottomorule`s, the first one aligned with the table, and the second one moved to the left:

[image]

How can I solve this?

**Update:** the error occurs only if babel is used in italian, all the other languages I tried work well.

Comment: I must say that even if you load `[italian,english]`  so  that english is the main language, you have the error, whereas with `[english] ` alone, there's no error. That's very strange.

Comment: Depending on the document, the alternative way to define languages can be a solution. Perhaps not so complete, but in many cases will be enough: `\usepackage{babel} \babelprovide[import,main]{italian}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `etoolbox` which is loaded by italian. It inserts a hook in the end-environment code and tabularx doesn't like this.

With the development version of latex, which you can use by calling `pdflatex-dev` it works, its hook code is more robust.

Alternatively you could try the b-argument of xparse:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{b}
               {\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X}\toprule #1  \bottomrule\end{tabularx}}
               {}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
    Foo\\
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `pdflatex-dev` doesn't work for me, but `etoolbox` does. Thanks for the explanation too!